JavascriptException Stale element not found after (multiple) redirects
I'm building a SeleniumBase scraper that takes a set of tasks and performs them on a website. After performing some actions on the site the script calls driver.execute_script("return window.variable;"). This works fine on all domains I've scraped even with any redirects after clicks.
Today I scraped a new website which includes pressing two buttons that both redirect you to a page (2 redirects total). After the redirects the script runs execute_script and throws a selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.12.3/envs/tagprotection-v3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 478, in __call__
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/victor/Webvitals/tagprotection-v3/tagprotection/worker.py", line 28, in __collect_datalayer
    datalayer = sb.execute_script("return window.variable;")
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.12.3/envs/tagprotection-v3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/seleniumbase/fixtures/base_case.py", line 3372, in execute_script
    return self.driver.execute_script(script, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.12.3/envs/tagprotection-v3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 414, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {"script": script, "args": converted_args})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.12.3/envs/tagprotection-v3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.12.3/envs/tagprotection-v3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: {"status":10,"value":"stale element not found in the current frame"}

I'm not quite sure why this javascript variable is a stale element. Data is being pushed to it on every page (similar to Google's dataLayer)

it's probably trying to return an object (possibly a reference) and Selenium's trying to convert that to a WebElement.  The error message is sort of odd... not sure I can interpret that but I think it's coming straight from the JS engine.  Pure guess here... what is it you are expecting to be returned?  Are you waiting until all the redirects are finished and DOM is in steady state?

What I believe to be the problem is that I'm calling the execute_script function and assigning it to a variable before the new page is fully rendered. I am waiting for the dom to be ready using SeleniumBase's wait_for_ready_state_complete()

those sorts of waits are not reliable... (when does it start polling dom state exactly?  you can't really know... does a script get loaded then fired after readystate.... etc...)  Use a webdriverwait with an explicit expected condition to check for a webelement that will only exist when complete.  (and check for stales, re-get, etc...)

I've tried waiting for an element to be visible and just wait for 10 seconds timing out a function. Both times I still get the error.

remember that each redirect is going to wipe all window globals.  You might also confirm the driver's current context... (do you ever switch it to a frame or another tab?  is it currently at the top-level?)  What exactly is this variable and what do you expect to be returned?  (that may point to the root issue here...)

I do not switch any frames/tabs. The variable holds an array of arrays/json objects. The scraper goes to the site, presses a button and waits for redirect twice. Then the element is stale even though it does exist on the page. Here is a screenshot of the variable on the page https://i.imgur.com/H9hIZDK.png

I'm thinking that Selenium thinks it's an array of webelement references.  You might try just getting one property (string or number) to see if that works.  (if so, get them one at a time...)
